# Cant figure out how to sort list by these criteria

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

Basically I have an arraylist of  objects which have a name and startDate and they are in a similar initial order to :

Frank 10/20/1990

Bill 1/2/1990

Frank 2/2/1990

John 9/8/1990

Bill 4/4/1990

Frank 5/1/1990

I'm trying to order them such that for each new customer name declared, all of the customer objects with the same name must be placed next to each other in ascending order of their dates, so the final sorted list should look like:

Frank 1/1/1990

Frank 5/1/1990

Frank 10/20/1990

Bill 1/2/1990

Bill 4/4/1990

John 9/8/1990

I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours to no avail, hopefully someone can help me thanks in advance!

Comment: What language are you using?  If Java, then considered using a sorted collection.

Comment: Yep I'm using java, could you guide me a bit as to how I would use that to sort my list

Comment: Is the start date an actual `Date` object, or is is text?

Comment: It's a date object, it's a date and you can compare  two dates with getTime, i wrote that format in the question instead of the proper format with hours and minutes for simplicity, sorry about that

Comment: @FrankBilliams In the future, tag your Question with the programming language.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do that from now on!

Answer (score 1):

[Java collections framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) does not have a sorted list, so this answer gives you a way to sort a given unsorted list.  If you want to actually *maintain* a sorted collection, then you can look into things like a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) such as [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

You can define a custom comparator for the class containing the name and date (let's call it `Wrapper`), and then sort the list using it:

```
public static Comparator<Wrapper> wrapperComparator
                      = new Comparator<Wrapper>() {

    public int compare(Wrapper w1, Wrapper w2) {
        if (w1 == null && w2 == null) {
            return -0;
        }
        else if (w1 == null && w2 != null) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (w1 != null && w2 == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (w1.getName().equals(w2.getName()) {
            return w1.getDate().compareTo(w2.getDate());
        }
        else {
            return w1.getName().compareTo(w2.getName());
        }
    }
};
```

Now use this custom comparator to sort your list with the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) utility.

```
Collections.sort(yourList, wrapperComparator);
```

Note that I have made some assumptions here.  I assume that your list might have null values, in which case I treat nulls as being *greater* than any other value.  I also assume that a given `Wrapper` object will never have null names or dates.  If this isn't the case, you'll have to add some null checks to the above code.

Comment: Thanks for this! But this doesn't  keep the original name declarations in order, and sort things in alphabetical order instead

Comment: `original name declarations` ... where is this information given, or even described, in your question?  If you don't want to sort alphabetically, then you have to specify how you want to sort your data.

Comment: sorry, I'm a bit bad with the wording but in the original question I wrote out the original list and how the final list would be, you can see since Frank was the first declared name, so I had to get all the objects with Frank as the name, and sort them in date order, and then since Bill is the next unique name declared in the original list, I needed to get all the Bill's, sort them into date order, and then John is the next unique name declared, etc.

Comment: It's going to be a bit of work to get this.  Also, it isn't clear if this additional ordering shouls be associated with the wrapper class.  Perhaps someone else can give you code.